# how can i draw pyramid with php?

Tags: php

I can draw a pyramid using ASCII-art pyramid with the code below:

```
<center>
<?php 

$number = 10;

for($i=0;$i<$number;$i++)
{
    for($a=0;$a<$number-$i;$a++)
    {
        echo $i;
    }
    echo '<br/>';
}
?>
</center>
```

But if I set `$number` to something larger than 9 (e.g. 10), this will not work anymore, because 10 is made out of two characters. Therefor if the number consists of two characters and would originally be printed `n` times, it should only be printed n/2 times.

But I do not know how to do that, can you help me write it?

Sample output:

[image: pyramid]

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but I don't get it. The title of the question is asking for a "pyramid"...ANSI Art?

Comment: @FabianLauer ANSI Art? I thought it is called ASCII Art.

Comment: @Kamil: You made me Google this and you're right, it's ASCII Art (ANSI Art exists, though. Knew it :)

Comment: @FabianLauer I went deeper and i have read about that on Wikipedia. There are ANSI and ASCII art, ANSI is using more characters :)

Comment: @ubercooluk - The homework tag is obsolete. I have removed it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<style type="text/css">
    div {
        width: 20px;
        display: inline-block;
    }
</style>

<center>
    <?php

    $number = 20;

    for ($i = 0; $i < $number; $i++) {
        for ($a = 0; $a < $number - $i; $a++) {
            echo '<div>' . $i . '</div>';
        }
        echo '<br/>';
    }
    ?>
</center>
```

or

```
<center>
    <?php

    $number = 20;

    for ($i = 0; $i < $number; $i++) {
        if ($i > 9) {
            $j = $i + round($i / 2);
        } else {
            $j = $i;
        }
        for ($a = 0; $a < $number - $j; $a++) {
            echo $i;
        }
        echo '<br/>';
    }
    ?>
</center>
```

Comment: If you are using CSS - maybe add perform center align in CSS, instead of HTML <center> tag?

Comment: no problem, but I just want to learn. I'm doing this for learning.

Answer (score -1):

I am just practicing PHP and to expand my PHP knowledge I came here and found this question. Though it is 1 year back. But I found a solution about this. So, I think it would be very easy to solve this problem.

```
for ($row=0; $row <= 9; $row++) {

for ($space=1; $space <= $row; $space++) {      
    echo "&nbsp;";
}

for ($col=$row; $col < 10; $col++) { 
    echo $row . " ";
}
echo "<br>";
```

}

#### Output Is

[image]